# Invariant violation: The title prop of a button must be a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set title dynamic in my navigation bar but i am getting an error.

I have done like this

```
const HomeScreen = (
    {navigation}
    ) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        // Update the document title using the browser API
        navigation.setParams({ name: 'Lucy' })
      },[]);

    return <View>

    </View>
}
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const titleMessage = navigation.getParam('name');
    console.log(titleMessage);
    return {
        headerRight : <Button title={titleMessage}/> 
    };
};
```

But its gives me an error

Comment: I think Button closing tag is incorrect. Try **<Button title={titleMessage}> Save </Button>**

Comment: could you please share detailed error log here ? that would be much helpful

Comment: @ManishMenaria no same problem

Comment: @VarunArya i had updated more code

Comment: What error do you get? Can you copy and paste the error message? And is enything logged on the console.log?

Comment: @ManishMenaria The button does not use a close tag. If you do that, you have two titles.

Comment: Can you create a codepen/codesanbox link?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of code is not return a string

```
const titleMessage = navigation.getParam('name');
```

So I think you can first try to `console.log(titleMessage)` too see the data

Then use `.toString()` to convert into string since `title` is expecting a string

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it says cannot read property toString of undefined

Comment: do you have any data from `console.log(titleMessage)` ?